# Video and headphones issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a custom video player that works very well. I discovered a problem and would like to know if this is a problem of iOS or is there a way to solve. When I'm watching and listening to the video with headphones on and take off my headphones, the sound continues, but the video freezes.

I am using MPMoviePlayerController for video and AVAudioPlayer for audio.

Tks for help

Comment: Do you get any console-logs that you would like to share with us?

Comment: None. Just freezes video. Tks

Answer (score 0):

You can get a callback when headphones are unplugged from the device. This might be a good starting point.

Check out this SO question: [Headphones unplugged during playback cause bug on iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284452/headphones-unplugged-during-playback-cause-bug-on-iphone-app)